# Magento 2 Grid from external feed

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

Hi there is it possible to create an add admin uicomponent but have the data coming from an external data feed other than a collection. E.g an elasticsearch index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can load the data in from any location that you want. The DataProvider is responsible for handling the data that is passed to the UI component. That DataProvider (which should probably extend `\Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider`) can return anything desired.

If you take a look at this class: `\Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductCustomOptionsDataProvider`, you will notice that it is calling the `->toArray()` method on the collection. That is outputting an associative array to JSON. So the source of the data is less important than the structure of that data.

---

As a side note, UI Components are a focus for the devdocs team right now (9/29/2016), so expect to see a lot more good information coming to the currently-shallow documentation on this subject.

Comment: Excellent thanks for the info this will get me started.

Comment: Hi bassplayer7 I have managed to get the data from an external datasource into the grid, now i need to be able to search it with a free text field. I am using <filterSearch name="fulltext"/> in my ui component however i cannot find how to override the default search. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: That's good. I haven't worked much with search, unfortunately, so I don't have an easy answer right off. I suggest asking a new question if there isn't already one here, though.